# Using an CSV import in a power-shell workflow

Tags: powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have been trying for hours to get a workflow to work where i import a CSV and then use that list within the workflow but it seems nothing is being passed and i cant find for the life of me the correct way to do it, here is my script:

```
$SessionIDList = Import-CSV "C:\Users\smackenzie\Desktop\Shite\SessionIDList.csv”

Workflow CheckConnections
{

ForEach -parallel ($Connection in $SessionIDList){

$IP = $Connection.IP
$ConnectionName = $Connection.ConnectionName
$SessionID = $Connection.SessionID

#Test the connection 

$ConnectionStatus = Test-Connection -ComputerName $IP -Count 4 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Measure-Object ResponseTime -Maximum -minimum | select @{name='Maximum Time(ms)';expression={$_.Maximum}}, @{name='Minimum Time(ms)';expression={$_.Minimum}}

#Get the average connection latency

$ConnectionStatusAverage = ($ConnectionStatus.'Maximum Time(ms)', $ConnectionStatus.'Minimum Time(ms)' | Measure-Object -Average).Average

#Write the connection Status to a file

  if ($ConnectionStatus){
    $UPorDOWN = " ONLINE " + $ConnectionStatusAverage + "ms"

  }
  else{
    $UPorDOWN = " OFFLINE"
  }

  Set-Content -Path "C:\Users\smackenzie\Desktop\Shite\New Shite\$Connectionname.txt" -Value "$SessionID, $UPorDOWN"

}

}
```

Can anyone help me on how to pass the CSV list into the workflow?

When i run it nothing happens.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out i think:

I need this in the workflow:

Param (
        $SessionIDList)

And then this when i call it:

CheckConnections $SessionIDList